# How to close an Activity using push Notification in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on Firebase Push Notification and i want to close `MainActivity`. Application should finish when `onMessageReceived()` is called. I am also passing the `Context` but its not working. In this case, I'll send notification when application is opend. My code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new FirebaseMessagingService(MainActivity.this);
  }
}
```

**FirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends
             com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

    Context context;
    public FirebaseMessagingService(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        context.finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define a `BroadcastReceiver` in `MainActivity`, that calls `finish()` when triggered:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver finishReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        finish();
    }
};
```

Register/unregister it when appropriate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // ...

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
        .registerReceiver(finishReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(FirebaseMessagingService.ACTION_FINISH));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
        .unregisterReceiver(finishReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And then you just simply have to send a local broadcast from `onMessageReceived()`:

```
public static final String ACTION_FINISH = "yourpackagename.ACTION_FINISH";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
        .sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_FINISH));
}
```

(`FirebaseMessagingService` is a `Context` subclass, there is no need to pass another `Context` instance to it)